# What does surface integral define?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

What does a surface integral define.... what is the difference between $dS$ and $dA$ if any..?
I know that $dA$ give the volume of an function with 2 variables, but what about $dS$ does it do the same or what..?

[Trying to study using this material](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx)

Comment: $dS$ is a differential area over a curved surface. $dA$ is a differential area over a flat surface, usually in one of the cardinal xyz planes.

Answer (score 3):

These are just notations that confuses people a little. That is why I greatly prefer to write the integral of any function $f : A \subset \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ simply as:

$$\int_A f$$

But here comes what this notation is meant to tell you: we usually use $dA$ to say that we are integrating over some subset of $\Bbb R^2$. Now, a surface can be thought of as the resulf of taking pieces of the plane, bending then, and putting it all together in a smooth manner. When we integrate over a surface we usually use $dS$ to indicate that.

In the *old* and informal way of thinking about these, it was all about really small patches of area. So the idea is that $dA$ would be an infinitesimal patch of area in the plane and $dS$ an infinitesimal patch of area on some arbitrary surface. These notions however, tend to just complicate things instead of simplify, so the modern treatment doesn't use this anymore.

Just as curiosity, these $dS$ and $dA$ only make sense when you go to Differential Geometry. In this context, these will be the "volume forms" of the manifold. So $dA$ would be the "standard notation" for the volume form in the plane and $dS$ would be some "standard notation" for the volume form in arbitrary surfaces. And of course, "volume" in this context is just the area.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ stands for *Area* and an integral versus $dA$ is an integral over an area - that is plane.

$S$ stands for *Surface* and an integral versus $dS$ is an integral over surface itself - that can be curved or plane.

The confusing part is often comming from the fact that the projection of a curved surface on the carteisan coordinates' planes e.g. $xy$ or $xz$ or $yz$ is an area.

Extension:

Regarding your second comment/question I think what may be confuses you is the term "volume". Indeed height plays a role beacuse a surface when curved *curves* in a *volume*. But a *volume* can be also an area as in DG. In order to understand this suggest you have a toy experiment: take a piece of paper and build a surface then examine $dS$ as well $dA$ visually. For $S$ the paper curved in space and for $A$ plane. Then try to find ways to put them in relation for instance $A$ could be plane projectin of $S$ or an infitessimal piece of $S$ (just mark a smal piece with a pen) can be approximated by $A$... Then imagine to walk on the $S$ and sum up all you see on the landscape ($u$,$v$) and the same when walking on $A$. It will give you an intution of what is the difference.

Hope this helps you more visually.

Comment: but usually when you take a surface integral you multiply a F(r(u,v)) with crosproduct of the v derivative of r and the u derivative of r.

But shouldn't the crossproduct give the areal, and f(r(u,v)) the hight and thereby the volume?

Comment: @user81636 see extension above!

Comment: Ehh... 
that part may have confused me more than necessary...
I still dont get it..

I think that my definition of dS and dA is wrong.. 
I mean when you do a dobbelt integrale, you either find the area og volume of the given bounderies.. 
dS gives me the area around a plane or what?.. 
I looked it up on wikipedia..
and it said

"It can be thought of as the double integral analog of the line integral. Given a surface, one may integrate over its scalar fields (that is, functions which return scalars as values), and vector fields (that is, functions which return vectors as values)."

Anaolog???

Comment: Maybe a concrete definition of an plane and a surface.. since plane can be curved.. right?

Comment: no no surface can be curved and plane is plane.